# Custom Split Normal Data not rendering properly, but does on random frames?

Tags: rendering, normals, geometry

I'm having this issue where I have custom split normals on this character, and it's fine in viewport. But when I hit render I get something that looks like I've cleared the normals, which looks a lot worse. But whats more odd is every now and then on random frames I'll get the correct looking split normals? Any thoughts?

What they are supposed to look like on every frame:
[image: Good Split Normals]

What "most" of the rendered animation looks like:
[image: Bad Split Normals]

You can clearly see it on the back of the arm. it does it for all armour pieces in different areas making it really noticeable.

I've tried clearning the split normals and using auto smooth at different angles but that always looks not right, and tried recalculating normals, which made it looks worse all the time.